# changing the url by post method in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to change the url path by submited form...

## index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include 'file.php'; ?>
        <form action=<?php action(); ?> method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Choose ID by select tag</legend>
                <label>ID:</label>
                <select name="id" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                    <?php option(); ?>
                </select>
                <label><?php selcet(); ?></label>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

## file.php

```
<?php

function action() {
    $value = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

    if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
        $value .= '?id=' . $_POST['id'];
    }

    echo $value;
}

function option() {
    $count = 3;

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
        $value = 1;

        if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
            $value = $_POST['id'];
        }

        if ($i == $value) {
            echo '<option value="' . $i . '" selected>' . $i . '</option>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</option>';
        }
    }
}

function selcet() {
    $value = 1;

    if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
        $value = $_POST['id'];
    }

    echo 'Option ' . $value . ' selected.';
}

?>
```

the action() function not working as well, I'm getting wrong ids, I want to get ?id=2 while '2' selected.

Can someone help me please? Thanks! :)

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want the URL to show the selected option, or the option show what is in the url? The problem is you are trying to use POST and GET at the same time. If you want to use have the URL and the option selected match, then it is going to be through GET, not POST.

Comment: Are you trying to redirect? `header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . $_POST['id'])`

Comment: what do you expect to happen? You're embedding an `id` parameter into the form URL, and have a field with the exact same name in the form. since you're using POSt, you get `$_GET['id'] = value in url` and `$_POST['id'] = 'value from form field'` If you want the value in the URL, then you can't use $_POST, and have to check $_GET

Comment: @BrianLogan I want to show in the url the selected option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your original request:

`[...] I want to get ?id=2 while '2' selected.`

You need to use GET not POST for the easiest and fastest results.

`index.php`

```
<?php include 'file.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="<?php echo active(); ?>" method="GET">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Choose ID by select tag</legend>
                <label>ID:</label>
                <select name="id" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                    <?php echo option(); ?>
                </select>
                <label><?php echo select(); ?></label>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

`file.php`

```
<?php
function active() {
    $value = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $value .= '?id=' . $_GET['id'];
    }
    return $value;
}

function option() {
    $count = 3;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
        $value = 1;
        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
            $value = $_GET['id'];
        }
        if ($i == $value) {
            echo '<option value="' . $i . '" selected>' . $i . '</option>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</option>';
        }
    }
}

function select() {
    $value = 1;
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $value = $_GET['id'];
    }
    return 'Option ' . $value . ' selected.';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed.